# use Eloquent relationships while exporting data to Excel file in Laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1, maatwebsite-excel

I want to create a summary report of my two tables, one is employees table and the other one is sims table. These tables have one to many relationship. I know that we can export data of a model by using
`->fromModel($model)`
but is there a way so I can generate the report based on the two tables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SO, I asked a question and someone who could not answer but cowardly awarded -1. However, I figured it how to do this manually. Posting the code so it may help the future beginners like me.

```
public function downloadSummary(){

        Excel::create('records', function($excel) {

            $excel->sheet('Sheet1', function($sheet) {
                $employees = Employee::all();

                $arr =array();
                foreach($employees as $employee) {
                    foreach($employee->sims as $sim){
                        $data =  array($employee->id, $employee->name, $employee->nic, $employee->address, $employee->title,
                            $sim->id, $sim->msisdn, $sim->imei, $sim->issued_to);
                        array_push($arr, $data);
                    }
                }

                //set the titles
                $sheet->fromArray($arr,null,'A1',false,false)->prependRow(array(
                        'Employee Id', 'Employee Name', 'Employee NIC', 'Employee Address', 'Employee Title',
                        'Sim Id', 'Sim MSISDN', 'IMEI', 'Issued To'
                    )

                );

            });

        })->export('xls');
    }
```